IN SQL how to retrieve XML column data based on element
I have the XML inside one of the table columns, here I need to find rows based on 'DESCRIPTION' which is present in the table.
Sample XML column value
<Activity>
  <text value="ID:HELLO, DESCRIPTION:PROJECT112233 , CREDIT:1.83, INTEREST:3.77, TOTAL:5.60" />
</Activity>

I tried following , but its not working
DECLARE @Description varchar(100) 

SET @Description='PROJECT112233'

SELECT * FROM DataLogs WHERE 
ActivityDescription.exist('"+ @Description +"') = 1

Sample Data Build
create table DataLogs
(
    id int primary key,
    created_date date,
    ADescription XML
  )

INSERT into DataLogs 
values (1,'2024-04-16','<Activity><text value="ID:HELLO, DESCRIPTION:PROJECT112233 , CREDIT:1.83, INTEREST:3.77, TOTAL:5.60"'/></Activity>');
insert into DataLogs values (2,'2024-04-12','<Activity>
  <text value="ID:LO, DESCRIPTION:ECT112233 , CREDIT:0.83, INTEREST:0.77, TOTAL:1.60" />
</Activity>');
insert into DataLogs values (3,'2024-04-10','<Activity>
  <text value="ID:Junk, DESCRIPTION:CT33 , CREDIT:1.00, INTEREST:2.00, TOTAL:3.00" />
</Activity>');
insert into DataLogs values (4,'2024-04-01','<Activity>
  <text value="ID:Jk, DESCRIPTION:MT2313 , CREDIT:2.00, INTEREST:4.00, TOTAL:6.00" />
</Activity>');


Which dbms are you using? The above SQL code is product specific.

I am using SQL server

Something like: select ADescription .value('Activity[1]/text[1]/@value[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), * from DataLogs where ADescription .value('Activity[1]/text[1]/@value[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') like '%DESCRIPTION%' But your xml is weird. why do you store the attributes as one long text, it kinda defeats the whole idea of xml fields

Thank you siggemannen for the response, i agree that is the existing design and that's how data is stored in SQL table

I tried following code , but I am seeing 0 records , but records exist in the table : DECLARE @Description varchar(100)
SET @Description='MT2313'
select ADescription.value('Activity[1]/text[1]/@value[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), *
from DataLogs where ADescription.value('Activity[1]/text[1]/@value[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') like '% +@Description+ %'

Works fine for me https://dbfiddle.uk/T5LxR9SC

One way to do this would be to make use of the sql:variable() function in XQuery, e.g.:
declare @Description nvarchar(100) = N'DESCRIPTION:PROJECT112233';
select *
from DataLogs
where ADescription.exist('/Activity/text[contains(@value, sql:variable("@Description"))]') = 1;

Returns the output:



id
created_date
ADescription




1
2024-04-16
<Activity><text value="ID:HELLO, DESCRIPTION:PROJECT112233 , CREDIT:1.83, INTEREST:3.77, TOTAL:5.60" /></Activity>



